# How to persist data between views in MVC3 with JavaScript?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I want to pass data directly from one view to another in the two following situations:

1. Our users are allowed to dock and undock a toolbar that is persistent thoughout our application. I want this state to be saved when the user navigates to another page. The toolbar is docked and undocked using jQuery.
2. In some cases, after a successful response from an AJAX call we have a full page refresh or a redirect. We want to display a notification to the user after the refresh / redirect (eg. Your action was successful).

My initial thought was to use cookies, specifically using [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), but I was then wondering about using the `Session[]` variable. Given that our JavaScript will be in an external file I don't know if this is possible and if so does it simply complicate the issue?

Comment: Is there a reason for not setting the session data on the server side, before returning your ajax response?

Comment: @Justin The only reason I'm thinking where there may be a problem is that our `$(document).ready()` is in an external JavaScript file which will cause problems when querying the session data. I'd like to keep this externalised rather than utilising multiple `$(document).ready()`s

Comment: You wouldn't care about where your `$(document).ready()` is if you are using `Session`.  The `Session` lives on the server, so you would have to read/write to it on the server.  For example, you set some session data before returning your ajax response.  Then, later... you need to get some of that data, you would have to go back to the server to read that data (another ajax request).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Lawnchair?

http://brian.io/lawnchair/

Sounds pretty much like what you need. It is used to persist client side data across pages.

Comment: This looks very similar to the jQuery Cookie plugin? Is there any reason to use Lawnchair instead of jQuery Cookie if that's the way I decide to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

My application required me to store many data elements across views an sessions. Rather than pick a storage mechanism up front (mostly because management couldn't decide) I coded my app using [persistence.js](http://persistencejs.org).

I was able to pick the precise storage mechanism later with minimal impact to my code.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same type of problem.
after workaround I use a jQuery cookie and store the hidden panel id.
and check the cookie in `$(document).ready(function(){});` of jQuery that which panels are hidden and after make their `display:none`.So after postback the cookies are persist and the panels became hidden.
It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply sending your toolbar state information through hidden fields back and forth ( means from MVC view to controller and than from controller to MVC view ).